# Cant Launch a window with Selenium Chrome Driver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Environment:
Vs2019, C#
NuGet Package: Selenium v3.141.0 by Selenium Committee.
Chrome Driver from Selenium website - v92.0

IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver("FolderPath"); //time out error here.
Driver.url = "www.google.com"

with no other code, I can't get pass declaring Chrome Driver. I get a time out error with local host.
I tried:
setting a different port.
adding "no-sandbox" to arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add a chrome option:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.add("--remote-debugging-port=9222 ") // change port if necessary
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try utilizing the ChromeDriver NuGet package instead of pointing to a local file location
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/

Here is a simple example for you to reference

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace ExampleDemo
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Chrome_test
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [Test(Description="Go To Google")]
        public void GoToGoogle() {

            homeURL = https://www.google.com/;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDownTest()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }
}
```